# Easy way to continue a failed reindex?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm currently trying to reindex a large set of data (around 96 million documents) using the [Python API](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html), specifically the [`reindex`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#reindex) command.

When running the command I eventually get a timeout error from the `bulk` command. I've tried setting the `bulk_kwargs request_timeout` to 24 hours, however it still timesout... after 28 hours and 57 million records loaded.
Re-running the reindex will just delete the existing ones and start over.

Regardless of the reason why the error happens (I think I'm having problems with a disk bottleneck which I can fix. There are no `out of memory` errors) **is there any easy way to continue the reindex from where it died?**

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying that you're deleting the existing ones and start over, then just delete index and create new one and feed it. Will be faster.

**OR**

If you cannot have empty index, then one by one or using some batch delete items identified by some `id` and insert updated according to that `id`.

Comment: It will be faster but will eventually die in my current setup (or there is a high chance it will, which is a risk I can't take atm). I have no choice to delete the existing data as the [`reindex`](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#reindex) command will just overwrite the existing documents (**If you don’t specify the query you will reindex all the documents.**). So I'm not actually controlling the delete myself, the API is.

Comment: Could you define API, elasticsearch API or ...?

Comment: OK and what is your current setup? Could you add new functionalities?

Comment: What do you mean by "new functionalities"?
My setup is a 8 core, 8GB RAM, 1TB HDD debian box. The problems I have now is that the drive is the bottleneck; with multiple people using it, it's causing a timeout (I think). I'm gonna move it to a different drive (SSD) thats not being used and hopefully it will reindex. However this setup could be used later on similar production environments where deleting it all and restarting the reindex would be unacceptable, so I need a way to continue a reindex.

Comment: Ok, well... to give you better advice I should talk with you and get more info about, I don't think these comments are good for this, you can start chat if you want.